# IRF520 MOSFET Transistor to convert 3.3v to 5v?

Tags: relay, transistors

I'm *just* starting to poke around with ways to turn 3.3v in to 5v and I keep coming across MOSFET transistors.

I happen to have an [IRF520 MOSFET N-Channel Transistor](http://www.futurlec.com/Transistors/IRF520.shtml) lying around and am wondering if I can somehow use that to trigger a [5V relay switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008MPK0VE).

If that's doable, jow would I hook that up so I can use a digital out on a 3.3v microcontroller to ultimately trigger that 5V relay?

Comment: How is the microcontroller powered? You could take the 5V from USB (if available), this usually providers high enough current. I believe the IRF isn't really suited for 3.3V though, but you can try.

Comment: If you can get a “logic level” MOSFET, it will probably work better than your IRF520 for your application.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample schematic of turning on a relay using a mosfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMEmGp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Updated to include flyback diode and pull down to turn off if no input is connected

Comment: But be wary that the IRF530 may not be the best choice for 3.3V control.

Comment: The part numbers are the default for the schematic tool. The question indicates a 520 is intended to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You could (just about) use it as a low-side switch to a relay circuit (the *normal* relay circuit you get when you Google "Arduino Relay"), although it is far from a good choice for the job - the threshold is a bit too high to work well at 3.3V.

A MOSFET cannot magically convert 3.3V into 5V, but it can take a 3.3V signal and use that to switch another 5V power source on and off.